# Buss' Polynomial-Size Frege Proof of the Propositional Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, pigeonhole-principle

S. Buss described a polynomial-size Frege proof of the propositional pigeonhole principle in the paper [*Polynomial size proofs of the propositional pigeonhole principle*](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Esbuss/ResearchWeb/QuasiPolyPHP/paper.pdf) (the definition of the Frege proof system can be found in the paper). I found the proof very abstract, so I want to instantiate the proof in the case that $n=3$ (i.e., $3$ pigeons fly into $2$ holes). Define propositional variables $a,b,c,d,e,f$, where

- $a,b$ stands for pigeon $0$ flies into hole $0,1$, repectively;
- $c,d$ stands for pigeon $1$ flies into hole $0,1$, repectively;
- $e,f$ stands for pigeon $2$ flies into hole $0,1$, repectively.

Then the pigeonhole principle, i.e., that there must be some hole containing at least two pigeons can be formulated as

$$\mathrm{PHP}_3=(a\lor b)\land (c\lor d)\land (e\lor f)\to (a\land c)\lor(a\land e)\lor(c\land e)\lor(b\land d)\lor(b\land f)\lor(d\land f)$$

For example, $c\lor d$ means pigeon $1$ must fly into at least one pigeon, and $b\land d$ means hole $1$ contains both pigeon $0$ and pigeon $1$. To prove $\mathrm{PHP}_3$ is a tautology is to prove that $\neg \mathrm{PHP}_3$ is unsatisfiable. Now

$$\neg \mathrm{PHP}_3=(a\lor b)\land (c\lor d)\land (e\lor f)\land(\neg a\lor\neg c)\land(\neg a\lor\neg e)\land(\neg c\lor\neg e)\land(\neg b\lor\neg d)\land(\neg b\lor\neg f)\land(\neg d\lor\neg f)$$

Define $r_j^m$ be the propositional variable indicating that at least one of pigeons $0,1,\cdots,m$ occupies hole $j$, where $0\le m\le n-1$ and $0\le j\le n-1$. For example, $r_0^2=a\lor c\lor e$, and $r_1^1=b\lor d$. Let $\alpha(m)=\left|\left\{r_j^m=1|j=0,1\right\}\right|$ be the number of holes that are occupied pigeons $0,1,\cdots,m$. The basic idea of Buss' proof is to prove that $\neg\mathrm{PHP}_n$ implies $0<\alpha(0)<\alpha(1)<\cdots<\alpha(n-1)$, yielding $\alpha(n-1)\ge n$, which contradicts the fact that $\alpha(m)\le n-1,\forall m$. Numbers are encoded in a Boolean vector. For $n=3$, the numbers we concern are less than $4$, so a number $w$ can be represented by two Boolean variables $u_1$ and $u_0$, where $w=2u_1+u_0$.

Now we formulate the proof in propositional logic. Let $\alpha(m)=2u_1^m+u_0^m$, where $u_1^m$ and $u_0^m$ are propositional variables. It's clear that $u_1^m=r_0^m\land r_1^m$, $u_0^m=r_0^m\oplus r_1^m$, where $\oplus$ denotes exclusive-or.

- For $m=0$, $r_0^0=a$, $r_1^0=b$, so $u_1^0=a\land b$, $u_0^0=a\oplus b$, so $\alpha(0)>0$ is $u_1^0\lor u_0^0=(a\land b)\lor(\neg a\land b)\lor(a\land\neg b)$. Since $\neg \mathrm{PHP}_3\to a\lor b\to (a\land 1)\lor(b\land 1)\to(a\land b)\lor(a\land\neg b)\lor(\neg a\land b)$, this can be easily proved.
- For $m=1$, $r_0^1=a\lor c$, $r_1^1=b\lor d$, so $u_1^1=(a\lor c)\land(b\lor d)$, $u_0^1=((a\lor c)\land\neg(b\lor d))\lor(\neg(a\lor c)\land(b\lor d))$. $\alpha(1)>\alpha(0)$ can be formulated as $(\neg u_1^0\land u_1^1)\lor\left((u_1^0\leftrightarrow u_1^1)\land(\neg u_0^0\land u_0^1)\right)$, that is $$\left(\neg(a\land b)\land(a\lor c)\land(b\lor d)\right)\lor\left(\left(\left((a\land b)\land(a\lor c)\land(b\lor d)\right)\lor\left(\neg(a\land b)\land\neg((a\lor c)\land(b\lor d))\right)\right)\land\left(\neg((\neg a\land b)\lor(a\land\neg b))\land\left(((a\lor c)\land\neg(b\lor d))\lor(\neg(a\lor c)\land(b\lor d))\right)\right)\right)$$But I have difficulty deriving this formula. According to the paper, this formula should be derived by applying *Lemma 6*, but I can't figure out how is *Lemma 6* applied.

Let $\vec{v}$ be a Boolean vector, and denote by $T(\vec{v})$ the number of true components of $\vec{v}$. In my perspective, *Lemma 6* states that: for Boolean vectors $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r}'$, if for every $k$, $r_k'\to r'$, and there exists $h$ such that $r_h\land\neg r_h'$, then $T\left(\vec{r}\right)<T\left(\vec{r'}\right)$. I can't see how to apply this lemma.

So my questions are:

1. Is my understanding of the lemma correct?
2. If the lemma is correctly stated, how can we use it to derive the formula I mentioned above?

Thanks!